# How do I get subclass to initialize property as its correct class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class named `SPPanelManager`, which has a property of another class, named `SPPanelSettingsManager`. SPPanelManager has the following in it's `-init` method:

```
self.settingsManager = [[SPPanelSettingsManager alloc] init];
```

The purpose of `SPPanelManager` is to be subclassed, and the subclasses are used throughout my app. For example, there's `SPGreetingManager`. In the .h file of `SPGreetingManager`, I have declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SPGreetingSettingsManager *settingsManager;
```

which makes the settingsManager be of the correct class. The problem is that when the `SPGreetingManager` subclass is initialized, it calls the init method above, and initializes the settingsManager as the `SPPanelSettingsManager` class, rather than `SPGreetingSettingsManager`.

How can I get it to initialize this as the correct class for that property without having to re-write the init code in every subclass?

Comment: Is this ***self.settingsManager = [[SPPanelSettingsManager alloc] init];*** in your SPPanelManager init method?

Comment: How about using a base class of `SPGreetingSettingsManager` and `SPPanelSettingsManager` as a `settingsManager` property class, then ask for the particular subclass at some method with an assertion when `SPPanelManager` subclass doesn't provide the class ? Or just use a default class for the `settingsManager` initialization in this case.

Comment: I'd suggest using an `-initWithPanelManager:(SPPanelManager *)manager` method to properly inject your deendency class.

Answer (score 8):

The super class (`SPPanelManager`) somehow has to know which class the concrete panel manager wants to use as a `settingsManager`.

Apple uses the following approach to match CALayers to UIViews:

The base class declares a class method that returns the concrete `SPPanelSettingsManager` subclass:

```
// in SPPanelManager.h
+ (Class)settingsManagerClass;
```

... which subclasses override to return their custom class:

```
// in SPGreetingManager.m
+ (Class)settingsManagerClass
{
    return [SPGreetingSettingsManager class];
}
```

Now the superclass can instantiate the settings manager as follows:

```
self.settingsManager = [[[[self class] settingsManagerClass] alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another common solution is to use a naming convention. Just match the names of the classes: `SPGreetingManager` has a `SPGreetingSettingsManager`.

By definition each ...Manager has to have a matching ...SettingsManager.

```
// in SPPanelManager.m init
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
className = [className stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Manager"
                                                 withString:@"SettingsManager"];
Class settingsManagerClass = NSClassFromString(className);
NSAssert(settingsManagerClass != Nil, @"no settings manager class found");

self.settingsManager = [[[settingsManagerClass settingsManagerClass] alloc] init];
```

The advantage is that subclasses don't have to override a common method to declare the class type. On the other hand it might seem a bit obfuscated what's going on.

Also, above code forces a one to one relationship between the classes. No settings controller could be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Is SPPanelManager a class you developed? Simply give it a init with a parameter for the settings instance.